# Изменение ссылок в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо заменить ссылки с редиректом 301 на прямые ссылки. Ссылки, которые нужно изменить, находятся в разных местах — как в статьях, так и в услугах и др. страницах. В большинстве своем они находятся в определенном блоке на странице.
[image: блок со ссылками]

В связи с тем, что я не разбираюсь в Wordpress, хотелось бы уточнить:

- раз этот блок просто находится в данном поле — значит он не является шаблонным блоком?
- есть ли возможность в wordpress просто заменить ссылку на другую массово или придется менять в каждой странице отдельно?

Answer (score 1):

> есть ли возможность в wordpress просто заменить ссылку на другую
> массово или придется менять в каждой странице отдельно?

Для массовой замены есть плагины. Например [BRS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)